# Card generator with some calculations

Tags: javascript

Basically, I am creating a random math generator.

the first line has a random number from 1 to 99
also, the second line has a random number from 1 to 99

and we also generate a random operator (*, +, -),

and the last line bold is the result of the calculation.

---

on click, we call a function that generates a div with all the logic,

and we used `<template>` to do something like react but with HTML only.

---

I see that there is some repetitive things, but not know how to improve, it will be helpful if you help!

[image]

```js
class Card {
#CONTAINER = document.querySelector("#container");
#TEMPLATE = document
    .querySelector("template#card")
    .content.querySelector("div")
    .cloneNode(true);

  constructor() {
    this.container = this.#CONTAINER;
    this.template = this.#TEMPLATE;

    this.container.appendChild(this.template);
  }

  get element() {
    return this.template;
  }
}

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  generateCard();
});

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  generateCard()
}

function generateCard() {
  let card = new Card().element;

  let cardOutputs = {
    first: card.querySelector(".first-number"),
    second: card.querySelector(".second-number"),
    result: card.querySelector(".result-number"),
  };

  let arrRandom = [];

  let operationsArray = ["+", "-", "*"];

  let randomOperation =
    operationsArray[Math.round(Math.random() * (operationsArray.length - 1))];

  Object.values(cardOutputs).forEach((output, index) => {
    if (cardOutputs.result !== output) {
      arrRandom.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
      output.textContent = addZeroPrefix(arrRandom[index]);
    } else {
      if (randomOperation === "+") {
        addiction();
      }

      if (randomOperation === "-") {
        if (arrRandom[0] > arrRandom[1]) {
          subtraction();
        } else {
          addiction();
        }
      }

      if (randomOperation === "*") {
        multiplication();
      }

      card.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
      });

      function addiction() {
        card.querySelector(".operator").textContent = "+";
        output.textContent = addZeroPrefix(arrRandom.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
      }

      function subtraction() {
        card.querySelector(".operator").textContent = "-";
        output.textContent = addZeroPrefix(arrRandom.reduce((a, b) => a - b));
      }

      function multiplication() {
        card.querySelector(".operator").textContent = "*";
        output.textContent = addZeroPrefix(arrRandom.reduce((a, b) => a * b));
      }
    }
  });

  function addZeroPrefix(num) {
    if (num < 10) {
      return `0${num}`;
    }

    return num;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-blue-200 h-screen grid grid-rows-[1fr_auto]">
  <div id="container" class="container mx-auto py-10 px-4 flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-4  grid-cols-3 overflow-auto"></div>

  <div class="grid place-items-center w-full px-4">
    <button id="btn" class="py-4 w-full max-w-screen-md shadow-sm text-2xl bg-white hover:scale-95 hover:shadow-2xl transition rounded-lg mb-4">generate</button>
  </div>

  <template id="card">
      <div class="h-min p-6 rounded-xl bg-white hover:-translate-y-2 hover:shadow-lg hover: shadow hover:rotate-2 hover:scale-105 transition text-2xl">
        <div>
          <div class="flex gap-4">
            <div class="first-number flex-grow">errpr</div>
            <div class="operator">error</div>
          </div>

          <div class="flex gap-4 border-b-2">
            <div class="second-number flex-grow">error</div>
            <div>=</div>
          </div>

          <div class="result-number font-bold">error</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

> expand the code snippet to full screen to see the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Review

Your code is way too complex

The `Card` object is not a card, rather it is a utility function to copy a template. There is no need for it or you could have implemented it as a singleton with static functions and properties to create cards.

The generate card function has complicated what is just a simple substitution task. There are about 50 lines of code for a task than can be done in a quarter of that.

The HTML template contains unneeded content, Eg `<div class="operator">error</div>` that has typos, eg `<div class="first-number flex-grow">errpr</div>`

You can use `eval` (it is not evil) to evaluate the result of the operation on the two random values. This will greatly reduce the complexity of the source code. see rewrite.

Use `String.padStart` or `String.padEnd` to pad strings. This will simplify the function

> ```
> function addZeroPrefix(num) {
>   if (num < 10) {
>     return `0${num}`;
>   }
>   return num;
> }
> ```

to

```
const addZeroPrefix = num => (num + "").padStart(2, "0");
```

Avoid indirect calls You use a function to call a function.

> ```
> document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", () => { generateCard(); });
> ```

This is redundant and just makes code noisier and thus harder to maintain and read. The line can just be

```
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", generateCard);
```

### Random Bug

You state that the values are from 1 - 99 yet you generate random values via `Math.round(Math.random() * 100);` which will create values `0` to `100` with the values `0` and `100` being half as likely as any of the other values.

To create a random value within a range and a even distribution you can use something like.

```
const rnd = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
const randNumber = rnd(1, 99);
```

### Rewrite

Rewrite uses a static object `Card` to create a card from a template via the function `Card.create`. There is no need to instantiate the class.

There are helper functions at the top to simplify and reduce the verbosity of DOM APIs.

The function `rnd` and `rndItem` create random values.

`generateCard` uses `Card` to create a card and then adds it to the page.

I have remove the scroll into view as I could not see why it is needed. To add a card the button needs to be in view, and if the button can be see the next card will also be in view.

I removed all the CSS styling as you did not provide the CSS (only a indirect reference `"https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"`) and added some basic CSS just for the answer.

Using templates forces you to use classes to reference elements. Ideally element ids are best for referencing elements as it means you do not need to change code if you change the CSS and class names. Personally I would have created the card in code rather than via a template

```js
const qry = (qStr, el = document.body) => el.querySelector(qStr);
const append = (el, ...sibs) => sibs.reduce((p, sib) => (p.appendChild(sib), p), el);
const rnd = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
const rndItem = items => items[rnd(0, items.length)];
class Card {
    static create() {
        const card = qry("div", qry("#cardTemplate").content).cloneNode(true);
        const num1 = rnd(1, 99) + "", num2 = rnd(1, 99) + "", operator = rndItem("+-*");
        const result = (eval(num1 + operator + num2) + "").padStart(2, "0");
        qry(".first",    card).textContent = num1.padStart(2, "0");
        qry(".second",   card).textContent = num2.padStart(2, "0");
        qry(".result",   card).textContent = result;
        qry(".operator", card).textContent = operator;
        return card;
    }
}
function generateCard() { append(container, Card.create()); }
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", generateCard);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<div><button id="generateBtn">Generate</button></div>
<template id="cardTemplate">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="first"></div>
            <div class="operator"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="second"></div>
            <div>=</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="result"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: you are genius, you literally make the code better! I need to learn all these topics. like `.reduce()`, `.padStart()` etc... you make me even better! thanks @blindman67

Comment: yeah very cool https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart, also the `qry` function is literally genius! hope you do a good sunday!

Answer (score 2):

#### Split the loop

The `forEach` loop in `generateCard` does two very different things:

- If the current object is not the result, then generate a random number and write it as the text content into the object
- If the current object is the result, then compute the result of the random operation based on previously generated random numbers

This assumes that the result object will be the last one in the iteration.

This is not a good use case for a loop.
It would be better to split the loop,
and do the necessary operations in a simple sequence of steps:

1. Generate two random numbers
2. Compute the result of the random operation on the random numbers

#### Use `else if` or `switch` for mutually exclusive conditions

In this code:

> ```
>   if (randomOperation === "+") {
>     // ...
>   }
>
>   if (randomOperation === "-") {
>     // ...
>   }
>
>   if (randomOperation === "*") {
> ```

Only one of the conditions will be true,
so these should be chained together using `else if` or a `switch` statement.

#### Use `const` when possible

Many of the variables declared with `let` are never reassigned.
So it's good to make them `const`.

#### Use better names

`arrRandom` and `operationsArray` include the term "array" in the name,
which is unnecessary.
I suggest the more natural, descriptive names `randomNums` and `operations` for these.

Comment: thanks a lot! really, if I can tomorrow or 2 days in the future (date based on StackOverflow policy) I will add you a bounty of 50/100. very well answered!, for now, accepted and upvote)

Comment: Hey thanks, I appreciate the sentiment, and it's really not necessary! Keep up the good coding, see you around! (And you may still get more and better answers too!)

Comment: thanks, @janos, now I saw a better answer, but thanks a lot! I will ask my friend to upvote also your answer so you don't lose points, sorry. you do a good job